# How to calculate leave-out-median using PL/SQL analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write an analytic function in PL/SQL that, when applied to a column within a table, returns for each row in the table, the median of the column excluding the given row.

An example to clarify: Suppose I have a table TABLE consisting of one column X that takes on the following values:

```
1
2
3 
4 
5
```

I want to define an analytic function LOOM() such that:

```
SELECT LOOM(X)
FROM TABLE
```

delivers the following:

```
3.5
3.5
3
2.5
2.5
```

i.e., for each row, the median of X, excluding the given row. I've been struggling to build the desired LOOM() function.

Comment: What is the "given Row" in your example?  Not clear

Comment: How far have you come with your function, do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a "clever" way to do this.  You can do the calculation with a correlated subquery.

Assuming the `x` values are unique -- as in your example --

```
with t as (
      select 1 as x from dual union all
      select 2 as x from dual union all
      select 3 as x from dual union all
      select 4 as x from dual union all
      select 5 as x from dual
     )
select t.*, 
       (select median(x)
        from t t2
        where t2.x <> t.x
       ) as loom
from t;
```

EDIT:

A more efficient method uses analytic functions but requires more direct calculation of the median.  For instance:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as x from dual union all
      select 2 as x from dual union all
      select 3 as x from dual union all
      select 4 as x from dual union all
      select 5 as x from dual
     )
select t.*, 
       (case when mod(cnt, 2) = 0
             then (case when x <= candidate_1 then candidate_2 else candidate_1 end)
             else (case when x <= candidate_1 then (candidate_2 + candidate_3)/2 
                        when x = candidate_2 then (candidate_1 + candidate_3)/2
                        else (candidate_1 + candidate_2) / 2
                   end)
        end) as loom
from (select t.*,
             max(case when seqnum = floor(cnt / 2) then x end) over () as candidate_1,
             max(case when seqnum = floor(cnt / 2) + 1 then x end) over () as candidate_2,
             max(case when seqnum = floor(cnt / 2) + 2 then x end) over () as candidate_3
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by x) as seqnum,
                   count(*) over () as cnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the table always have 5 values and those values are 1 .. 5?

Comment: @CarlitosWay . . . This is the data provided by the OP; the code makes no such assumption about the number of rows or the values in the rows.  If you downvoted a correct, tested answer, that is rude.

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of correlated query T ??

Comment: you should explain (somehow) that T is mocking the table for the example and should be not used as literal answer (that was why I misunderstod your solution) ...